# Codeigniter and GoCardless php calls always resulting in 'Call to member function on a non object'

Tags: php, codeigniter, payment-gateway

I am using the GoCardless PHP library https://github.com/gocardless/gocardless-php with CodeIgniter and am trying to test a simple subscription call.
However, each time I try to call any of the functions it always results in a 'Call to member function any_function() on a non object'.

I have tried numerous things I've found from even the deepest, darkest places on the Internet, but nothing is solving the problem.

I have loaded the library

```
$this->load->library('gocardless');
```

Then tried passing an array into

```
$subscription_url = GoCardless::new_subscription_url($sub_details);
```

If anyone can help, it would be gratefully appreciated as I am tearing out what is left of my hair.
If you need any more code, please let me know.

Comment: What is the _exact_ error you are getting? i.e. including file and line number? Could the CodeIgniter object `$this->load` not be set?

Comment: Hi, the error is
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function new_subscription_url() on a non-object in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/rewards/system/libraries/Gocardless.php on line 117
But the function changes depending on what method I call.
Line 117 calls
`public static function new_subscription_url($params) {
    return GoCardless::$client->new_subscription_url($params);
  }`

Comment: Can you see what method initialises `GoCardless::$client`? Perhaps there is a factory method or init routine that needs to be called first.